# Parse and add debug statements in C++ source code file

Tags: c++

I am tired of debugging a flow of my official project code - it spreads across multiple files and millions / thousands of line. Hence I started to write a C++ program that would take input file names from a file whose objective is add printf( ,**FILE** ,**LINE**); - extra debug statements after each C++ statements like:

```
void my_func()
{
call_other();
}
in file 1.cpp at line 1
```

Would become

```
void my_func()
{
call_other();
printf("call_other() 1.cpp 1")
}
```

So each file code would be parsed and this extra debug statement would be added.

But the issue comes up with various type of statements:

```
if(condition) statement else statement;
C++ templates
switch case
etc
```

I am not able to establish a grammar that I should follow, like:

If the line ends with a semicolon and next token is not '{' the add this debugging line.

I believe that there are more cases than I am thinking off. Any suggestions that I should consider before implementing the same across thousands of file accumulating to millions of line of code?

Is there a tool / known technique that I can already make use off?

Comment: describe the problem that the flawed solution is meant to solve, please

Comment: Also accept more answers. If you don't accept, people are less likely to answer.

Comment: Why not just step through the code using a debugger?

Comment: Why not just learn to use a debugger ?

Comment: I am trying to list all - the issue is that once I ran onto thousands of file and I start getting compilation error or flows breaks - it would be really troublesome to find issue cause of my modifications.

Comment: The issue of using debuggers is the first setup and next that I need to compile whole code with debugging options. This ends up with exe floating and run into disk space issue.

Comment: @Prakash disk space?! is this smth. embedded? Do you necessary need this source code transformation or do you just need to be able to view the actual sequence of function calls?

Comment: I need the source code transformation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely need to do this, take a look at [clang](http://clang.llvm.org), and write a source-to-source translator that works on the AST level.  There are various posts around the net that can get you started with this. One example: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/06/08/basic-source-to-source-transformation-with-clang/